# How to sync mysql slave without stopping master

Tags: mysql, replication

I found this method again and again and nothing else: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3229580/2307520

But not only it is not trivial, it also locks the master until I manually backup, copy and restore whole database, which would create unacceptable long service outage in my work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.

Slave and master databases are constantly on-sync through a network connection.

However, if the slave server needs to be reinstalled from **scratch** then you will need to make a backup copy of the status of the server using `mysqldump`. This copy is the starting point for the slave. You will nedd to LOCK the tables to avoid someone or something updating them during the copy.

The explanation says that you can use the command `UNLOCK TABLES` **even if the dump hasn't ended yet**, so it's **FALSE** that it locks the master until you manually `backup, copy and restore the whole database`.